# Firebase auth persistence not working in Chrome extension manifest V3 - how do I fix it?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I get this error while trying to set the persistence type to SESSION / LOCAL

`firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);`

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: The current environment does not support the specified persistence type. (auth/unsupported-persistence-type).
at J (assert.ts:122:55)
at $ (assert.ts:153:11)
at ci.setPersistence (persistence.ts:76:3)
at background.js:17:21
```

The only type I'm not getting error is when I set is to NONE. But the problem is, everytime my chrome extension is not open for few minutes, it will fire up firebase.initailizeApp again which log user out!

This making my app really useless.

This is what my code looks like

```
try {
    self.importScripts('/firebase/firebase-app.js', 'firebase/firebase-auth.js', 'utils.js', 'const.js');

    //
    const firebaseConfig = {
// config
    };

    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const auth = firebase.auth(app);
    auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);

    // const auth = firebase.auth();
    console.log(`auth is ${auth}`);
    console.log(`currentuser is ${auth.currentUser}`);
```

I expect it to persist my user authentication state. So that they don't need to re-login everytime the extension *sleeps*.

My chrome version is  113.0.5672.126, and use Standard Protection option for security. (in browser settings)